# Refactor PHP legacy arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, refactoring

I have some legacy code that is all but clear, clean and concise. Much of that legacy logic lies in using arrays. Like this code here:

```
if (isset($statistics[$lowerInstance])) {
        $statistics[$lowerInstance][$size]['count'] +=     $items[$lowestType]['count'];
        $statistics[$lowerInstance][$size]['amount'] += $items[$lowestType]['amount'] + (($items[$highestType]['amount'] / $items[$highestType]['count']) * $items[$lowestType]['count']);
    } else {
        $statistics[$lowerInstance][$size]['count'] = $items[$lowestType]['count'];
        $statistics[$lowerInstance][$size]['amount'] = $items[$lowestType]['amount'] + (($items[$highestType]['amount'] / $items[$highestType]['count']) * $items[$lowestType]['count']);
    }
if (isset($statistics[$higherInstance])) {
        $statistics[$higherInstance][$size]['count'] += $items[$highestType]['count'] - $items[$lowestType]['count'];
        $statistics[$higherInstance][$size]['amount'] += $items[$highestType]['amount'] - (($items[$highestType]['amount'] / $items[$highestType]['count']) * $items[$lowestType]['count']);
    } else {
        $statistics[$higherInstance][$size]['count'] = $items[$highestType]['count'] - $items[$lowestType]['count'];
        $statistics[$higherInstance][$size]['amount'] = $items[$highestType]['amount'] - (($items[$highestType]['amount'] / $items[$highestType]['count']) * $items[$lowestType]['count']);
    }
```

This is only a fraction of this particular method, it goes on and on.

I'm having some difficulty how to make it clearer and easier to work with. It is not as easy (I think) to just move multidimensional array to an ArrayAccess type object although that might be a slight improvement.

Is there some generic way of refactoring multidimensional arrays, or some examples of how it might be done? Not just on this particular problem but a more generic way to handle PHP multidimensional array hell?

Comment: At the core should be: 1) *Understand* what this code is supposed to accomplish. 2) Reimplement that task in the sanest way you can, replacing the old crap code. – Of course there may be ways to get from here to there incrementally by slowly replacing parts of the old code with the new one, but how that may play out in practice specifically for your case is impossible for anyone to tell.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm somewhat hoping for a silver bullet but I guess there just isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

I took some help from Martin Fowler's book, Refactoring: [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672).

**Replace Array with Object**

So I read what he wrote very carefully and decided to have a go at it. I started to create a unit test for the method. Just a simple one where I would pass a bunch of data, export the outcome and use that outcome in the assertions. I did this before refactoring so I could run the unit test after each iteration to know if I had broken anything.

First order of business according to Fowler is to create a class with a public array that will replace the offending array:

```
class Statistics
{
    public $data = [];
}
```

I created the variable:

```
$statistics = new Statistics();
```

Then I replaced all instances of the variable, $statistics became $statistics->data

So for example:

```
$statistics[$higherInstance][$size]['count'] += $items[$highestType]['count'] - $items[$lowestType]['count'];
```

would become:

```
$statistics->data[$higherInstance][$size]['count'] += $items[$highestType]['count'] - $items[$lowestType]['count'];
```

This was interesting because it opened up to some new possibilities. What I did next was to refactor out some of the code into their own methods:

```
protected function getInstanceData(Statistics $statistics, $higherInstance, $size, $highestType, $items) {
    $statistics->data[$higherInstance][$size]['count'] += $items[$highestType]['count'] - $items[$lowestType]['count'];
    ...
    return $statistics->data;
```

Then I would move that method into the Statistics class itself:

```
public function getInstanceData($higherInstance, $size, $highestType, $items) {
    $this->data[$higherInstance][$size]['count'] += $items[$highestType]['count'] - $items[$lowestType]['count'];
    ...
    return $this->data;
```

I did so with several chunks of the code. I didn't particularly like the parameters but
for now, I think it was an improvement, the code was atleast a little bit less noisy.

I removed the return $this->data from all the methods as it was no longer necessary,
the array was now contained within the Statistics class.

This opened up for further refactorings, breaking up the array further and delegating some of the responsibilities to new classes.

I think this is probably how I will deal with these type of arrays from now on, isolate them to classes and then break them up.